# Is it ok to include a very large css file inside 'styles' in angular2?

Tags: sass, angular

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import {Home} from './components/home/home';
import {About} from './components/about/about';
import {RepoBrowser} from './components/repo-browser/repo-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'seed-app',
  providers: [],
  pipes: [],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  styles: [require('bootstrap.scss')],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: 'app/seed-app.html',
})
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/home',       component: Home,        name: 'Home', useAsDefault: true },
  { path: '/about',      component: About,       name: 'About' },
  { path: '/github/...', component: RepoBrowser, name: 'RepoBrowser' },
])
export class SeedApp {

  constructor() {}

}
```

The important part is

> styles: [require('bootstrap.scss')],

So bootstrap(the css library) is pretty big but I want to use it in my angular2 app so I made the main component have Encapsulation of none so it will share the styles with the page and then I included bootstrap.scss as suggested.

My question is: is it ok to have such a large string (thousands of lines) inside the *styles* performance wise? is it better to put bootstrap in the head of the page like a regular css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular2 will provide a build step (still work in progress AFAIK) that does such processing before the app is served to the browser. If you use this, it shouldn't matter, orherwise I'd try to avoid using large CSS files this way. Even when there is no rewriting to do because you are using `ViewEncapsulation.None` everywhere, Angular2 might still parse the CSS which is redundant work.

Comment: I would rather not use such large files inline. Even when using `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` or `Native`. I mean those styles will be loaded asynchronously and in most cases you want your css before your page loads, no? I would just use the component inline styles to style specific components or if you ship a component as a third party component. For what do you use it?

Comment: With `Emulated` Angular has a lot of rewriting to do (shouldn't matter with the build step), with `Native` it wouldn't work at all because of shadow DOM boundaries that can't be crossed by CSS. I guess the build step will add the CSS to `index.html` directly anyway with `None` and `Emulated`

Comment: Ok thats true but the CSS will be added later in time and not before your scripts load.